# VLC - how to open the folder of the current playing video

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

I got a bunch of videos inside a folder, I just double click the video then close the folder, after the video is done playing, I want to open the another video in the folder, but I'm too lazy to find and open that folder again. How can I open the folder of the current playing video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Image worth thousand words
[image: VLC - open current video folder]

Yet, in case you prefer words:

1. Switch to playlist with Ctrl+L
2. Right click the video in the playlist and select `Show Containing Folder...`
3. Switch back to video with Ctrl+L

This is done with `VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax` or simply: VLC version 2.2.4.

Comment: Did you just asked a question to answer yourself?

Comment: [Which is totally fine](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: even he will get some award. it means that Stackoverflow encourages to move many official software documentation to here